# Can't get the correct format for my .screenrc

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, screenrc

This is my .screenrc. The goal, was for it to load up the client in the furthest left panel with a width of 85 (in gnome-terminal, FYI), the next section would be split in two, top and bottom. Both running a tail on two different files. And furthest right would be yet another tail occupying whatever space was left over.

```
startup_message off

term screen-256color
screen -t TinTin++ 0  bash
select TinTin++
split -v
focus down
screen -t Map 1 tail -f -s .01 $HOME/tintin/minimap
select tail
split -v
focus down
screen -t Group 2 tail -f $HOME/tintin/group
select Group
split
focus down
screen -t Chats 3 tail -f $HOME/tintin/Aardwolf-chats
select Chats
focus down
select TinTin++
altscreen on
```

EDIT: Getting closer with this code, but still not right.